# C# Webbrowser Programmatically Clicking Youtube Video

Tags: c#, youtube, browser

I'm currently trying to programmatically click a youtube video (in order to pause/play it) that's loaded in a WebBrowser control, yet nothing is currently happening.

My current code:

```
HtmlElement VideoElement = Browser.Document.GetElementById("ytPlayer");

if(VideoElement != null)
{
    VideoElement.InvokeMember("onClick");
    VideoElement.InvokeMember("click");
}
else
    Debug.Print("Could not find youtube video element!");
```

The video element is not returned as null, yet there is no result when invoking both events "onClick" and "click". Does anyone know what else could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
VideoElement.RaiseEvent("onclick");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but might help anyway. There is a Javascript API to the player if you are embedding the Youtube video. Have a look at the Player demo, where you have javascript links to play and pause the video.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

--Christian